# Python self: Do I have to pass self into a function to refer to self?

Tags: python

Question is confusing. Here's an example.

```
class some_class():
  some_var = 5
  def some_fun(self):
     def another_fun():
         return self.some_var
```

This is okay right? I don't have to have: another_fun(self) to call self?
I actually tested it and it works. I just wanted some clarification because it makes me a bit unsure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case it is not needed because `another_fun` is nested into the other functions, so it *captures* the local names from that function, and that includes `self`. Actually, any name accessible from `some_fun` will also be accessible from `another_fun`.

This is what some call a *closure*, and it's great to write functions that create functions. The classical example is:

```
def MultiplyBy(x):
    def M(y):
        return x * y
    return M

Double = MultiplyBy(2)
Triple = MultiplyBy(3)

print Double(10), Triple(10)
```

That will print `20 30`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, when you define one function inside another, the inner function can read variables from the outer one.  This is nothing specific to `self`.  It works for all variables in all functions:

```
>>> def outer():
...     a = 2
...     def inner():
...         print a
...     inner()
>>> outer()
2
```

In Python 2, you cannot rebind the outer variable in the inner function (i.e., you cannot do `a = 3` inside `inner` above).  In Python 3 you can do this with the `nonlocal` statement.

However, why are you doing this?  In the first place, your code above doesn't even call `another_fun`, so what it does is immaterial.  In general defining functions inside other functions is a bit of a strange thing.  There are certainly legitimate cases for doing it (e.g., decorators), but in many cases it's likely to cause confusion.

Comment: Actually, decorators are legitimate _and_ cause confusion.

Comment: @rodrigo: I didn't say the two situations were mutually exclusive :-)

Comment: no particular reason for doing this, just happened to do it by accident when changing up some code. thanks for the response